# How is "Repeated deletion" determined?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently deleted a question that already had an answer (the answer didn't solve the question, turned out to be a typo type issue), and saw the repeated deletion warning. I have seen a couple other meta questions with regards to this but have not found how "repeated" is determined.

Is this multiple deletions over a set period of asking history? Over total history? What are the number of deletions at which the warning is enacted?

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide - that gives the "limits" but otherwise, notices are issued giving a warning it may approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're warned every time you delete your own question if it has answers. Chances are, you're in no immediate danger of being blocked - the warning is just informational. But, there are folks who, for whatever reason, make a *habit* of deleting their questions as soon as they get an answer; needless to say, this is pretty annoying for the folks answering, and so the system penalizes it heavily (especially for very new users).

See also: [Better oversight for self-deleted answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244839/better-oversight-for-self-deleted-answered-questions)